# How to determine new price values from growth data

Tags: web-scraping, svg, data-analysis

I was able extract data from an SVG file that contains 1 week growth of a crypto currency (160 hours). The x1 values start from 6 and end in average 160 (about 160 values representing 160 hours in total). The Y2 values (also 160 mapped to each X1 value) represent the price growth of the coin and they range from 0 to 50. 50 seemed to be the highest point on the graph.

I extracted it and plotted on a chart and it corresponded to the shape of the SVG.

Is it possible to determine the next price of the coin in the next hour when I get the next growth data in the next hour?

I calculated the percent change between the last two hours using

((NewData - OldData)/ OldData) * 100

And used that *percentage along with the coin's *current price to find the *next price but it got it wrong. And I noticed again that the entire Y values can change sometimes, which makes sense as it's a "growth rate"

I heard something about regression analysis somewhere. I don't know if that's it

Oh! And by the way, I'm just a JavaScript dev. I used cheerio to read and extract from the SVG. And plotted the data using apexChart.